# How do I select a checkbox when I get a path error. I am doing this in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, path, cypress

```
cy.get('[data-ng-show="destact['dest'].length > 0"] > .checkbox-block > :nth-child(1) > .ng-binding').click()
```

the above is the path to my checkbox. As there are two single quotes, I tried to concatenate them as well but no luck

```
cy.get('[data-ng-show="destact['+'dest'+'].length > 0"] > .checkbox-block > :nth-child(1) > .ng-binding').click()
```

Comment: Can you add the html of element to your question ?

Answer (score 3):

Back-ticks are also valid delimiters for the selector,

```js
cy.get(`[data-ng-show="destact['dest'].length > 0"] > .checkbox-block > :nth-child(1) > .ng-binding`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the selector `[data-ng-show="destact['dest'].length > 0"] > .checkbox-block > :nth-child(1) > .ng-binding` is a correct selector, you can use backslash to escape the single quotes:

```js
cy.get('[data-ng-show="destact[\'dest\'].length > 0"] > .checkbox-block > :nth-child(1) > .ng-binding').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems seem to be occurring when selecting this attribute with the complex expression

```js
<div data-ng-show="destact['dest'].length > 0" ></div>
```

- the quote marks conflict
- the square brackets are ending the selector prematurely.

This will work if there's only one element with expression starting `destact`

```js
cy.get("div[data-ng-show^=destact]")
  .should('have.attr', 'data-ng-show', "destact['dest'].length > 0")
  .find('.checkbox-block > :nth-child(1) > .ng-binding')
```

If there's more than one element selected by `cy.get("div[data-ng-show^=destact]")`, you can add a filter for the exact expression

```js
cy.get("div[data-ng-show^=destact]")
  .filter((i, el) => {
    return Cypress.$(el).attr('data-ng-show') === "destact['dest'].length > 0"
  })
  .find('.checkbox-block > :nth-child(1) > .ng-binding')
```